# Who was the shadowy figure who approached Jean Leslie and seemed to undermine the deception?

Tags: plot-explanation, operation-mincemeat

[Operation Mincemeat](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1879016/?ref_=fn_al_tt_1) is a WW2 spy story about a plan to deceive Hitler by creating a fake identity for a soldier carrying secret information about Allied intentions in the Mediterranean theatre.  The central idea is to create a false identity for an officer whose body will be washed up on a spanish beach. The story is based on a real intelligence operation.

As part of the deception the body carries personal letters including a photograph of his girlfriend. The team running the deception used a photograph of Jean Leslie, a member of the team running the deception as the girlfriend.

Late in the movie, after the Germans have, apparently, bought the deception, Jean is approached by a shadowy figure who has a copy of the photograph but knows her real identity. He seems to want to know what is really happening but also claims to be a representative of an anti-Hitler faction in German intelligence. The team appears confused and don't know whether this means the deception has been rumbled or not.

Who was this shadowy figure? And does he represent something that actually happened with the real operation?

Comment: Wikipedia suggests that this operative (in both versions of the movie) was fictional. For instance in the original movie *"For example, the episode of the Irish spy, O'Reilly, is a complete fabrication."*

Comment: @Paulie_D Two issues. Who was the fictional figure in the context of the movie (it wasn't clear to me watching it). And was there some more complex interaction between the team and German intelligence in the real operation that was reduced to this fictional account to make a more cinematic story?

Comment: There was no interaction with German intelligence at all during the actual operation. In fact German spying in WW2 England was completely compromised by British intelligence. I suggest that you read the Wikipedia entry.

Comment: @Paulie_D Maybe that's what the wikipedia page says, but Canaris, the boss of the Abwehr was an anti-Hitler activist and had certainly tried to make better contacts in British intelligence. I thought the movie might be referring to that.